# NServiceBus Release Automation

Tags: nservicebus

We are using Microsoft's Release Management to promote code changes through the environments.  The installer creates the MSMQ queues if they are not already installed.  The problem is that creating the queues requires elevated privileges to correctly create the queues.  The release management agent account is an administrator on the local machine. The error message we receive is:

The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.

Is there a way to bypass the creation of the queues on the install phase and let the creation happen on service start up (which runs by default for us as Local System)?

We are open to any ideas to help get this service correctly installed and started.

**[UPDATE]**

Here is the message from the logs:
2014-09-03 08:47:55.522 -04:00 [Fatal] Exception when starting endpoint.
System.InvalidOperationException: There is a problem with the input queue: FormatName:DIRECT=OS:DNABUS1\private$\Purchasing.OrderEntry.Bridging. See the enclosed exception for details. ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_Transactional()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_Transactional()
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.QueueIsTransactional() in c:\BuildAgent\work\31f8c64a6e8a2d7c\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 144
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.QueueIsTransactional() in c:\BuildAgent\work\31f8c64a6e8a2d7c\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 153
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Init(Address address, TransactionSettings settings, Func`2 tryProcessMessage, Action`2 endProcessMessage) in c:\BuildAgent\work\31f8c64a6e8a2d7c\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 67
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.StartReceiver() in c:\BuildAgent\work\31f8c64a6e8a2d7c\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 245
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.Start(Address address) in c:\BuildAgent\work\31f8c64a6e8a2d7c\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 211
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Start(Action startupAction) in c:\BuildAgent\work\31f8c64a6e8a2d7c\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 806
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start() in c:\BuildAgent\work\31f8c64a6e8a2d7c\src\NServiceBus.Core\Hosting\GenericHost.cs:line 78

**[UPDATE 2]**

After disabling UAC on the target server and running "NServiceBus.Host.exe /install", the install and queue creation worked properly.  Does anyone know of a way we could do the install without disabling UAC on the target server?

Comment: Are you running the host install with NServiceBus.Integration argument?

Comment: I'm running "NServiceBus.Host.exe /install" from the automated release tool.  I've disabled UAC on the server and I'm still getting the same message.  The host operating system is ready (Perf Counters, RavenDB, MSMQ, etc) and waiting for an install.  I can run from an admin command prompt and it works correctly.

Comment: Another option may be to uses [PowerShell](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/managing-nservicebus-using-powershell) and install only what you want. This will require another step in your pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing is creating the MSMQ queues as a part of the release management template. That way, when by the time the service installer runs, the queues are already created, which allows us to keep UAC enabled.